# Button auto click function not working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript

I have found ways like this:

```
<script>
 window.onload=function(){
      document.getElementById('buttonid').click();
 </script>
```

to get my popup open by button trigger, but no matter what I do, it will not auto click on mobile. Can someone modify this to work on mobile devices? Thank you!

Comment: The script misses a closing `}`

Comment: you miss a `}` at the end. But with this problem your code should not work in desktop, as well.